# How the numeric value from numeric character is returned?

Tags: unicode

How is the numeric value from a unicode numeric character returned?  Is it from a table in a function?   Or a table in a font? Or?

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. Are you wondering how keyboard presses are received by the operating system and then passed all through the OS through multiple layers and applications into your program?

Comment: And what's with all the different tags? That alone makes this a candidate to be closed for being to broad. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: OP is asking about the `Numeric_Value` property in the UCD, which is how a Unicode library can figure out that ૨ (U+0AE8) is the digit 2 (in Gujarati, as it happens)

Comment: @rici With this extremely broad question, that's *one* possible way to interpret it. There are hundreds of other ways to interpret it as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I respectfully disagree. A Unicode numeric character is a Unicode character with General Category `Nd`, `Nl` or `No`, as per section 4.5 of the Unicode standard. Each such character has an associated "Numeric Value" property, as per section 4.6: "Numeric_Value and Numeric_Type are normative properties of characters that represent numbers." In the context of the Unicode standard, I see no other way to reasonably interpret the description "the numeric value from a unicode numeric character".

Comment: @free: I removed all the programming language tags from your question, since the question does not appear to be about any programming language in particular. If you are curious about a specific Unicode implementation in some programming language, you should ask a more precise question (or, in the case of open source libraries, consult the source code).

Answer (score 1):

The information is contained in the [Unicode Character Database (UCD)](http://unicode.org/ucd/). Any Unicode library must contain an implementation of this database, but the precise structure and implementation details will be specific to the library.

In most cases, the internal data structure is generated by a script during the compilation of the library. For example, the Python `unicodedata` implementation can be found in the [Modules directory of the CPython github repository](https://github.com/python/cpython/Modules). The implementation of the Unicode Data interfaces is in  `unicodedata.c`, and the database itself is in `unicodedata_db.h` (which is not really what I think of as a header file, but it is `#include`'d in the C implementation file. As a comment at the beginning of the database file indicates, that file is automatically generated by the script at  [Tools/unicode/makeunicodedata.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/unicode/makeunicodedata.py), which reads the official UCD files and generates the equivalent C code.

The numeric value data itself is contained in a column in the core [Unicode Data](http://www.unicode.org/Public/11.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) (in column 8), with some additional information in the data for [Han symbols](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/tr38-25.html). For convenience, numeric data is compiled into a simplified form as the [Derived Numeric Values table](https://www.unicode.org/Public/11.0.0/ucd/extracted/DerivedNumericValues.txt) (although I don't believe the aforementioned CPython implementation uses the derived data file.)

Note the the UCD is specific to a particular Unicode version, although there are stability guarantees, so libraries using a database preprocessor will need to be recompiled in order to adapt to a new Unicode version.

Comment: I kept my question short because i have a problem having my questions excepted.   I know about Unicode Character Database (ucd) and Unicode Data, field 8.   And i have seen The Derived Numeric Value table.   May question is were does python, C, or scheme get this information from, to return the numeric value?   I know it is not in the glyph.  May be in a table in the font.   Could be in a table in a function or procedure that returns the numeric value.   One of the authors of Annex #44 said it was in the operating system. I can not find the source code  to one of the functions to read?

Comment: @free: it's in a table in the unicode library being used. I don't believe any Operating System maintains this information, although it is certainly possible; if you have a quote, please provide a link.

Comment: @free: nobody can answer a question you don't ask; you need to be precise. As I said, if you want to know about some language, ask about it. Otherwise, it's just a guess what implementation you are interested in. So, I'm going to guess you are interested in Python. If that's the case, the place to start reading code is [Tools/unicode/makeunicodedata.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/unicode/makeunicodedata.py).

Comment: My question is were does python, C, or scheme get the information from, to return the numeric value?   Or were is table in the unicode library being used located?

Comment: @free: I added the pointers to the Python implementation. The point is that the data comes from the UCD; it is preprocessed into the library during the library build. So it's effectively hardwired into the library binary. There is no standard "C" library, but for C, C++ and Java, check out the ICU library, although that's a lot of code reading. (For the C/C++ implementation, the UCD is compiled during library build into a large binary structure which is mmap'd on demand.) I don't know of a Scheme implementation which provides the numeric_value property; more specific pointers would be helpful.

Comment: @rici You say "I don't believe any Operating System maintains this information", but at least the .NET framework has this functionality built in. To use your example of ૨ (GUJARATI DIGIT TWO), `Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetNumericValue('૨'));` prints 2.

Comment: @mrlister: the Net framework is a library, not an operating system. And it is the framework, not the OS, which holds the data, as the documentation makes clear: "Categorization of characters in a particular version of the .NET Framework is based on a single version of the Unicode Standard regardless of the underlying operating system on which the .NET Framework is running." (In the "notes to caller" section.)

Comment: So the table (that has the numeric data) is in .NET Frameworks  that the function refers to, to return the numeric value?    The table is not in the function?   Or does that depend on the program/function?

Comment: @free: not everyone uses .NET :-). See the CPython example in my answer.

Comment: @free: and the method being referred to in the .NET framework is also part of .NET, so it's certainly possible that the table is baked into the method. All I can claim from the documentation is that the .NET function does not have to look outside of the .NET framework to find the data. In particular, it does not ask the OS to provide it.